Why is pid changed in different terminal session?
I use WSL2 and was trying to use gdb to debug a c code following this gdb cheatsheet.
In summary it shows a way to call a python code solve.py that calls a c code, and displays the pid of itself.
And in another terminal session, I run gdb to communicate with the solve.py process by specifying the pid of solve.py.
However I realized I was failing to communicate with solve.py because the process pid was wrong. I ran ps and found out the solve.py was slightly different with what I saw in the first terminal. Can anyone explain why?
Below is a demonstration.
(env) junha@DESKTOP-3B9ANKQ:~/cs2107$ python3 solve.py
[+] Starting local process './test': pid 627
[*] Paused (press any to continue)

then I am supposed to run
gdb -p 627

as given in the cheatsheet.
But it doesn't work, and when I use ps a, I see that the actually pid is 624 not 627.
junha@DESKTOP-3B9ANKQ:~$ ps a
    PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    226 hvc0     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear --keep-baud - 115200,38400,9600 vt220
    231 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear - linux
    388 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
    389 pts/1    Ss     0:00 /bin/login -f
    508 pts/1    S+     0:00 -bash
    573 pts/2    Ss     0:00 -bash
    624 pts/0    S+     0:00 python3 solve.py
    627 pts/3    Ss+    0:00 ./test
    629 pts/2    R+     0:00 ps a

and below works:
gdb -p 624


The program says  './test': pid 627 and your ps says that test is process 627. All is well.

That page says print out the target binary's process id, so that's not the python script but the pid of the program you want to examine; in this case ./test

This is not a problem of WSL. I am afraid, you misunderstand the intentions of the tutorial.
With the script solve.py, the program python3 will start the target process for you (here called ./test). You want to attach gdb to that process, not to python3.
You may as well skip pwndbg for now and try with plain gdb ./test first. That will make the set-up simpler, but navigating gdb is more cumbersome. pwndbg adds some flavour, but the set-up can be confusing to the beginner.
